# can you make screen reader in android, skip specific elements?

Tags: android, android-studio, screen-readers

I'm writing an application and I'm adding Accessibility features to it.

when I turn on the screen reader, it also reads icons and other unnecessary items on the screen.

can you make the screen reader in android, skip specific elements?
or read a different text then what the elements say?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can control what it reads out by setting the `android:contentDescription` attribute on these elements.  If it's a purely decorative icon (for instance, one where the relevant text is already read out elsewhere), you can set the content description to `"@null"`.  On API 16+, you can also set these graphical elements' `android:importantForAccessibility`attributes to `"no"`.

You can find all of this and more information in [this guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/accessibility/apps#describe-ui-element).